# Change headphone left-right balance on Android 7

Tags: audio, stock-android, headphones, 7.1-nougat

What is the best way to set the left-right balance on a pair of earphones/headphones? I've looked into it, but I can't seem to find an easy way to do this.

I am on a rooted Nexus 6P on stock android 7.1.1

Does anyone know of a way to do this? I know very little about android development, so a simple solution would be best (preferably an app).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem.

My solution: root the phone with Magisk, install de Viper module and set the settings.

There's a lot of tutorials in xda, and it's pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have root, there are many apps on the Play Store which can do this. Just search for `stereo balance controller` and pick up an app which can run as a service and equalise the system audio.